# Datagridview control's forecolor only changes after the event handler runs AND another cell is clicked

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to change the color of a cell in a datagridview when the cell is doubleclicked. I've added a CellDoubleClick handler that fires properly after a cell is double clicked:

```
Private Sub myDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles myDataGridView.CellDoubleClick
    myDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
    myDataGridView.Refresh()  'I added this to try to fix the problem
    Application.DoEvents()    'I added this to try to fix the problem
end sub
```

But after the event 'fires' the UI does not change the color of the cell's text immediately. Instead, if I single click a **different** cell it then Visual Studio 2010 changes the **original** cell to red (like the handler says to do).

It seems like there is some sort of UI refreshing/UI repainting going each time I click a different cell. Is this correct? Is there a way to refresh the UI programatically. Many stackoverflow posts advise .refresh but this is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when you double click a cell it remains selected and the properties .SelectionForeColor and .SelectionBackColor are used.  Only when you click another cell does it become de-selected and begin using .ForeColor and .BackColor.  You can get it to update immediately by either also changing the .SelectionForeColor property or by setting .Selected = False immediately after.

Comment: I just figured that out too! Thanks!